First query executed in my SQLAlchemy app is much slower than subsequent ones
Summary
I'm building an API with FastAPI, Supabase and SQLAlchemy and using the ORM for a simple select statement on a table with one row takes 2-3 seconds, which is unacceptable.
Code
I have tried these two functions to query the Users table:
import time
from sqlalchemy import select, text
from app.models import User
from app.core.db_client import SessionLocal
from app.core.core_logging import logger


# Read users
@profile_decorator
def read_users_sa():

    # TAKES 2-3 SECONDS TO EXECUTE !!!!!!!!!!

    session = SessionLocal()
    users = session.query(User).all()
    session.close()
    
    return users

@profile_decorator
def read_users_raw_sql():

    # TAKES 0.36 SECONDS
    
    try:
        # Create session with minimal configuration
        session = SessionLocal()
        try:
            query = text("SELECT * FROM users")
            result = session.execute(query)
            users = result.fetchall()
            
            return users
        finally:
            session.close()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"SQLAlchemy query error: {e}")
        return None

This is my User SQLAlchemy model:
from .config.base import Base
from .config.shared import *  # shared imports that all the models use

class User(Base):

    """
    User model for storing user related details
    """

    __tablename__ = "users"

    # Required fields
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, nullable=False) # Foreign key added on dashboard
    team_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=True) # Future: references teams(team_id)
    first_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(64), nullable=False)
    marketing_opt_in = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    tracking_opt_out = Column(Boolean, default=False)

    # Optional fields
    birth_date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
    timezone = Column(String(4), nullable=True)
    address = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    billing_address = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    preferences = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    payment_method = Column(JSON, nullable=True)

    # Timestamps
    created_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))
    updated_at = Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable=False, server_default=text('now()'))
    
    # Constraints
    UniqueConstraint(user_id, name="unique_user_id")

And here's my DB client file:
from app.core.config import settings
from supabase import create_client, Client
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

url = settings.SUPABASE_URL
key = settings.SUPABASE_API_KEY

# Supabase client
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)

# SQLAlchemy engine
engine = create_engine(settings.POSTGRES_POOLER_URI)

# SQLAlchemy session
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Results

read_users_raw_sql() takes ~ 0.3s to execute

read_users_sa() takes 2-3s to execute


Additional context

The profile decorator is a custom decorator to measure the time it takes to execute a function.
The User table I'm querying has just one row and optional fields are null.
I know the ORM processes the response data and hydrates the User python object, so I expect worse performance than raw SQL. However, 2-3s is too long and I believe there's something wrong.
The same query on Supabase dashboard takes 0.05s, so Supabase isn't the problem.
The postgresql connection string has the following structure:

postgresql://postgres.<instance_name>:<pwd>@aws-0-us-east-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543/postgres
Question
If someone could shed some light on this, that would be great.

I tried using context managers for the session object
Changing the query with select constructor
I even reproduced the same scenario with a minimal example on sqlite and both the ORM and raw SQL were extremely fast
I also ran the functions with different networks and the difference in performance were consistent

All in all, none of this helped me solve the problem.
Edit
I changed the execution order of the two functions. I ran the raw SQL first and the ORM query second. Now the performance is reversed.
The first query executed after start-up seems to take 2-3s, whereas the subsequent ones are 10 times faster.

Take a look at the Postgres log and see what is happening at the database end.

How many rows are you fetching?

@IanWilson. From question:  The User table I'm querying has just one row and optional fields are null.

Ha ok sorry, I read it three times still never saw that.  Obviously way off but with such a small example it's hard to know what's going on.  For example if there is some sort of tear down issue that's going on.  Maybe the first connection is slower than the second connection for example.

I guess if they haven't tried it it might be good to try looking at the first 10 runs of each function separately.  Also the is the echo flag on create_engine as well as echo_pool: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.echo_pool

Are you running these functions during the same script?  If so the first call is going to bear the cost of creating the connection, which might be expensive for a remote server. Ideally you should execute the functions with a proper profiler to see where the time is going.

I added some additional information. It turns out the first query executed after starting up the app takes 2-3s, no matter which method is used — raw SQL or ORM.

I wrote this script to try this out on my local machine but its just local app server --> local db server so the numbers are microscopic and might not scale to what you're dealing with.  Also I'm not a network expert but depending on how you are starting things up there might be a delay just to resolve the DNS, especially if you are dynamically assigned different servers via the same domain name.
This is kind of weird to test because sqlalchemy pools only allocate connections on demand and usually just 1 per thread or 1 per task.  So it is easy to think you are connecting but you are either not connecting or just re-using the same connection from the pool but I think this test script avoids that.  Obviously don't open up tons of connections in the same main thread like I'm trying to do here for anything other than testing.
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pprint import pprint

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from time import sleep


def get_engine(env):
    PG_URI = f"postgresql+psycopg://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}"
    return create_engine(PG_URI,
                         echo=False,
                         echo_pool='debug',
                         pool_size=5,
                         pool_timeout=5,
                         pool_pre_ping=True,
                         connect_args={
                             "connect_timeout": 5,
                             "options": f"-c statement-timeout={5 * 1000}",
                         },
    )


def test_engine():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    connections = []
    connection_times = []
    try:
        for _ in range(5):
            b4 = datetime.now()
            conn = engine.connect()
            print (conn.execute(text('SELECT 1')).fetchone())
            connections.append(conn)
            connection_times.append(datetime.now() - b4)
        pprint (connection_times)
        pprint (connections)
        print (f'max={max(connection_times)}')
        print (f'min={min(connection_times)}')
        print (f'avg={sum(connection_times, timedelta(seconds=0)) / len(connection_times)}')
        print (f'unique={len(set(connections))}')
    finally:
        for conn in connections:
            conn.close()
    engine.dispose()


def main():
    test_engine()
    sleep(1)
    test_engine()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Note there is a ton of output from the pool_echo="debug" flag but the script spits out some numbers, it seems the first connection always takes longer but this data set and ms are so small I don't know if that is reliable.
-- the first call
[datetime.timedelta(microseconds=15121),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=7246),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=9117),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=6799),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=7614)]
[<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58b18aced0>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1b3b90>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1b3b50>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1b3c50>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1b3bd0>]
max=0:00:00.015121
min=0:00:00.006799
avg=0:00:00.009179
unique=5

--- the second call
[datetime.timedelta(microseconds=11134),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=6415),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=8002),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=6963),
 datetime.timedelta(microseconds=8338)]
[<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58b18aced0>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1c3250>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1c3590>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1c3b50>,
 <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f58af1c3ed0>]
max=0:00:00.011134
min=0:00:00.006415
avg=0:00:00.008170
unique=5


I guess I'm curious if every connection is 2s the first time or if just the very first connection is slow.  Maybe pointing to some sort of network level latency.  Maybe avoidable by just priming things by connecting once when the server starts up.
